# What is a difference between zip and tgz format?

Tags: zip, compression, tar

I want to install scala at [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html?_ga=2.142470774.574450871.1551689637-1180109525.1551688871) and I'm concerned about which one to download: zip or tgz. What is a difference between these, and what are the use cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different [archive formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file). They are used because it saves bandwidth and because they bundle files.

[Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) is more common on Windows and there is a decompressor preinstalled.

Tgz is [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) + [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) and is common on Linux. There is also a decompressor preinstalled, most of the time. Also known as .tar.gz.

If you're on Windows I'd download the zip or the installer, as you don't have to install a third party program to open it. If you're on Linux I recommend installing scala through your package manager.

Comment: They both use exactly the same deflate compression. It's just the archive format that's different.

Comment: Since [December 2017](https://curl.se/windows/microsoft.html), Microsoft [Windows 10 and newer also includes `tar` by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows).